# Scheduled run based on User chosen time on Windows 10 UWP

Tags: scheduler, uwp

I have a requirement for the Windows 10 UWP app, where user can select a date and time and a task will be executed based on that. I tried this with TimeTrigger, however if the user selects a time which is less than 15 minutes from now it doesn't work as we need to provide at least 15 minutes for the TimeTrigger to run.

Any workaround or confirmation that it is not possible on Windows 10 would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If FreshnessTime is set to less than 15 minutes, an exception is thrown when attempting to register the background task. It is built-in behavior.

Another way can be using DispatcherTimer but I'm not sure if it is suitable in your case. It depends on requirements for your app.

Comment: Will dispatcher time run in the background? Do you have any idea what would be memory and battery usage?

Comment: Tick handler is executed on the UI thread, so it is probably not suitable for you.If you aren't doing anything with the UI thread in your Tick handlers, you could also use ThreadPoolTimer instead. Also, for techniques like ThreadPoolTimer or a .NET Task, you aren't totally isolated from the UI thread. You could still assign to the UI thread asynchronously using CoreDispatcher.RunAsync.

Comment: Thank you, However I think I am almost aware these things. Do you know any solution that works on the background? Even user restarts the device/phone, the schedule should work at the selected time. User will never open the UI again once scheduled. So should not be on UI.

Comment: Can any one help? Any official confirmation saying, it is "NOT" possible on Windows UWP at the moment would be also appreciated, so that I can stop researching and spending my time and effort.